# Why float x = 99999999 - 2 does not result in x == 99999997?

Tags: c++

I have the following code,

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    float x = 99999999 - 2;
    cout << "x: " << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`cout` outputs `1e+08` instead of `99999997`. Why?

Comment: This is the same problem as in the question marked as duplicate, i.e. finite precision, just in the other direction (large numbers rather than small numbers).

Comment: Try http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter to see the next smaller float that you can generate.